# How to prove |a-b|≤|a|+|b|?

Tags: absolute-value

I am struggling with

> $$ |a-b|\leq |a|+|b|$$

Can anyone please help? Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I can only prove that |a-b|≥|a|-|b|, but don't know how to prove |a-b|≤|a|+|b|

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ real numbers?   do you know the triangle inequality?

Comment: The question mentions "Prove the following inequalities for all numbers a,b"
and the triangle inequality is |a+b|≤|a|+|b|, am I correct?

Comment: @Rhizaria Yes, that's correct. To prove this inequality, try to apply the Triangle Inequality to the numbers $a, -b.$

Comment: Thanks! I can prove it now!

Comment: $|a-b|=|a+(-b)|\le|a|+|-b|=|a|+|b|$

Answer (score 3):

$|a-b| = |a+(-b)| \leq |a| + |-b| = |a| + |b|$.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the given inequality can be proved simply as the guys commented above, but I liked to share with you a nice way used in proofs, that is "PROOF BY CASES".

---

Consider $6$ cases;

---

CASE(1): $a \ge 0,b \ge 0,a \ge b$

We have: $|a-b|=a-b$, we have: $|a|=a$, and we have: $|b|=b$

So, the given inequality, $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$ becomes $a-b \le a+b$ which reduces to $-b \le b$ which is true since $b$ is positive.

---

CASE(2): $a \ge 0,b \ge 0,a \le b$

We have: $|a-b|=b-a$, we have: $|a|=a$, and we have: $|b|=b$

So, the given inequality, $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$ becomes $b-a \le a+b$ which reduces to $-a \le a$ which is true since $a$ is positive.

---

CASE(3): $a \le 0, b \ge 0$

We have: $|a-b|=b-a$, we have: $|a|=-a$, and we have: $|b|=b$

So, the given inequality, $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$ becomes $b-a \le -a+b$ which is clearly true.

---

CASE(4): $a \le 0, b \le 0, a \ge b$

We have: $|a-b|=a-b$, we have: $|a|=-a$, and we have: $|b|=-b$

So, the given inequality, $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$ becomes $a-b \le -a-b$ which reduces to $a \le -a$ which is true since $a$ is negative.

---

CASE(5): $a \le 0, b \le 0, a \le b$

We have: $|a-b|=b-a$, we have: $|a|=-a$, and we have: $|b|=-b$

So, the given inequality, $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$ becomes $b-a \le -a-b$ which reduces to $b \le -b$ which is true since $b$ is negative.

---

CASE(6): $a \ge 0, b \le 0$

We have: $|a-b|=a-b$, we have: $|a|=a$, and we have: $|b|=-b$

So, the given inequality, $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$ becomes $a-b \le a-b$ which is clearly true.

---

All cases are considered above, and there is no more cases to be considered. Therefore, the given inequality always holds true.

---

Hope this helps.